# How to use 'orderByChild' in the nested children on firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my data structure:

```
{
 projectId:{
   projectName,
   projectTime,
   questionId:{
     answerCount
   }
 }
}
```

I tried to query the result ordered by `answerCount`, here is the code I wrote:

```
let refReadProject = firebase.database().ref('projects').child(aProjectId);

refThis.refReadProject!.orderByChild('questions/answerCount').on(
    'value', ....
```

It returns me the same result without ordering, is there any misunderstandings in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Instead `orderByChild('questions/answerCount')` try writing `orderByChild('questionId/answerCount')`. Or try: `let refReadProject = firebase.database().ref('projects').child(aProjectId).child(questionId); refThis.refReadProject!.orderByChild('answerCount').on(...`